# Why was my useful answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Why was this answer deleted?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37534627/1232524

> [image]

I have researched the question extensively and, IMO, my answer provides the easiest and most reliable solution to the problem these days.
I have even added some context after a comment asked for it, even though none of the other answers provided much. In fact, all of the other (active, upvoted and accepted) answers would be worth deleting if the community cared about applying SO answering standards relentlessly for every answer, not just new ones...

Comment: Screenshot please :) I cannot see it (<10k pleb life)

Comment: @Seth Here you go: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ45h.jpg

Comment: Truth be told, I don't get it. The top answer is a one-line link-only answer. Maybe your post got into the "Late answer"-queue, that'd atleast explain the focus on your answer.

Comment: All of the existing answers are terrible by today's standards.  But when adding new answers to old questions, your answer will go through the Late Answers review and that is likely what started the delete process rolling.

Comment: IMHO the question should be closed and I have voted for that.

Comment: That last delete vote made me punch a wall. It was cast *almost a full day after you edited your answer* to include context. **That is not OK.**

Comment: How are the other answers "active"? One was edited a day ago to fix the broken link (which is the only content of the answer), the others haven't seen any activity for years.

Comment: @Kyll "active" in the sense of visible and not deleted.

Comment: @BoltClock To be fair, the whole answer reads a bit like spam. So if I wasn't careful, I would've deleted it as well.

Comment: @Mysticial You seem to have a rather wide definition of spam. Besides that, what use are delete privileges if we give them to members of the community that don't exercise the necessary care when using them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In fact, all of the other (active, upvoted and accepted) answers would be worth deleting if the community cared about applying SO answering standards relentlessly for every answer, not just new ones...

That's not entirely true.  Your answer wasn't deleted specifically because it was a new answer and the others ignored because they were old.  When users answer old questions, the answer is immediately thrown into a "Late Answers" review queue.

While there, reviewers were asked to review **your answer** (they don't see any of the other answers), and a couple reviewers chose to vote to delete it.  Your edit did improve things, but once it picked up a few delete votes, it would have been more visible to very high rep users with full delete privileges and the last vote [came more easily than maybe it should have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324292/why-was-my-useful-answer-deleted#comment351434_324292).

Now that you have brought attention to the question, the community is looking more closely at the other answers since they are all terrible by today's standards.  A couple of the answers have picked up additional downvotes now and all have comments asking the users to expand their answers.  Plus the question has been closed.  But deleting them is not nearly as simple because they are upvoted.  Users with delete privileges cannot vote to delete answers that have positive scores, so they can't necessarily get the same "treatment" as yours did (but the entire question could get deleted if it got enough votes, which scales based on the overall score of the question and the score of the answers).

Comment: We can delete the whole question though(in 2 days time).

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. FWIW, in my opinion the question is in fact helpful and so is my answer. In other words had the question and my answer popped up in a Google / SO search it would have saved me a good bit of time researching a solution to this problem. Since Android native libs crashing is fairly common I do think others could benefit from this question/answer chain.